# Manipulating jquery templates when added

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-templates

I have a situation similar to the sortable demo: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/ , except the items are dynamically added with a jquery template. I'd like to make them sortable and draggable, but I can't seem to do that the usual way. The only solution that's vaguely similar is to hook it up using .live(), but there doesn't seem to be an appropriate event to subscribe to when a template is added (or removed).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `.delegate()`?  In many ways, it is superior to `.live()`

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: It still has the problem of needing an event to subscribe to.